# adding hash table struct with array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, hash

```
typedef struct veri{
int k[9],v[10];
}v;
v a[27];
int h(int x){
return x%27;
}


int put (v data){
if(a[h(data.k)].k == -1){
    a[h(data.k)] = data;
    return 1;
}
else {
    int donusSayisi =0;
    int indis = h(data.k);
    while(a[indis].k != data.k && a[indis].k!=-1){
    //printf("%d %d %d \n",a[indis].k, data.k, indis);
        indis ++;
        if(indis>=27){
            if(donusSayisi>=1){
                printf("hashtable dolu\n");
                return -1;
            }
            indis = indis %27;
            donusSayisi++;
        }
    }

    a[indis].v[indis]= data.v[indis];
    a[indis].k[indis] = data.k[indis];

}
```

}

ı am trying create hash table with array .But ı cant add it .I cant put it and get it.Where is my mistake.I am getting crazy because of this errors.This not my all code just a part..

```
if(a[h(data.k)].k == -1){
```

passing argument 1 of 'h ' makes integer from pointer without a cast 
comparison between pointer and  integer

```
return a[indis].v;
```

return makes integer from pointer without cast

Comment: "because of this errors" - well maybe include them in the question? and please, format your code better... it's hardly readable this way

Comment: you have to show the errors

Comment: `a[i].k = -1;` : `a[i].k;` is array, not an `int`.

Comment: a[i].k is an array of 9 integers. Which one are you trying to set to -1? All of them, the first one...?

Comment: @pm100 all of them but ı am trying write to a[27] array and print it

Comment: for(int i = 0;i<27;i++){
 for(int L=0;L<9;L++)
  a[i].k[L] = -1;
}

Comment: @EsmaeelE ı edited put function. -1 is just a check if(a[h(data.k)].k == -1) empty or full

Comment: @haktans4 Its not clear first you must initialize struct elements. for example assign some arbitrary value (-1) to it.

Comment: I ask again , what are you trying to do with this line `a[i].k = -1;`. Which of the 9 k integers in are you try to set to -1. If all of them then you need another loop.

Comment: I initialize sturct from main. v data;
 srand(time(NULL));
 for(int i=0;i<27;i++)
    {for(int j=0;j<9;j++){
                if(j==0){
                    data.k[j]=1;
                }
                else if(j==1){
                    data.k[j]=rand() % 6 ;
                }
                else if(j==2){
                    data.k[j]=0;
                }
                else if(j==6){
                    data.k[j]=rand() % 5;
                }
                else {
                    data.k[j]=rand() % 10 ;
                }
            }
            put(data);
 }

Comment: the error you show on `if(a[h(data.k)].k == -1)`. h is a function that takes a single integer. You are passing it an array of 9 integers. That cant work. What integer do you want to pass to h?

Comment: @pm100 no ı am trying to check it if(a[h(data.k)].k is -1 thats mean a[h(data.k)].k is free. ı can add a value in it.

Comment: @pm100 ooo ı get it.Thats right . k mean student number and v is student code . how can check it in my way ? with another int element ?

Comment: Let's put it this way, if you declare `int k[9] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};` you can't do `if ( k == -1 )`, becuase you cannot compare an array directly with a scalar.

Comment: @Bob__ yes ı cant reconize it. But ı must create hash table. And ı need to check free spaces in memory. what can ı do for this ?

Comment: By *"k mean student number and v is student code"* do you mean that k is a 9 digits number and v is a 10 digits one (I noted that your hash function only takes a single `int`)?. If that is the case you don't need two arrays, but just two `int`s.

Comment: You should use char * for student number. not int[9]. Thats very unnatural.The you can use NULL as meaning empty.

Comment: @Bob__ yes when ı wanna get student data when ı enter value in main  and program must print 'v'

Comment: @pm100 yes but hash table need int value for placement

Comment: Change your [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) so that it takes an array (of ints or chars) and returns a single int. You can, for example, sum all the values in the array and *then* take the remainder.

Comment: ım done with arrays for this example. I use linked list  because ı cant handle it